# Get value from XML in python using xml etree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I'm trying to get a value from a xml string but it's throwing attrib can't be retrieved from None type.

Consider below XML

```
<summary-report>
  <static-analysis>
    <modules>
     <module sev0issue="0" sev1issue="14">
     </module>
    </modules>
</static-analysis>
<dynamic-analysis>
    <modules>
     <module sev0issue="0" sev1issue="14">
     </module>
    </modules>
</dynamic-analysis>
</summary-report>
```

How to parse and get the sev0issue under static analysis tag?

I'm trying below code to get the value.

```
value= ET.fromstring(XmlData) 
issue= value.find('.//summary-report/static-analysis/modules/module')
issueCount= issue.get('sev0issue')
```

When I try this I'm getting error like there is no attrib sev0issue for Nonetype

Comment: Where is the code? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XmlData = '''<summary-report>
  <static-analysis>
    <modules>
     <module sev0issue="0" sev1issue="14">
     </module>
    </modules>
</static-analysis>
<dynamic-analysis>
    <modules>
     <module sev0issue="0" sev1issue="14">
     </module>
    </modules>
</dynamic-analysis>
</summary-report>'''

summary_report = ET.fromstring(XmlData)

# Method 1 prints both values from static and dynamic analysis
for a in summary_report:
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            print(c.attrib['sev0issue'])
print()

# Method 2
print(summary_report[0][0][0].attrib['sev0issue'])
```

outputs:

```
0
0

0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why, but with ElementTree you don't start searching from the root element. The correct version would be:

```
issue = value.find('.//static-analysis/modules/module')
issue.get('sev0issue')
```

If you use lxml, on the other hand, it's more intuitive:

```
from lxml import etree
value= etree.fromstring(XmlData) 
values.xpath('/summary-report/static-analysis/modules/module/@sev0issue')
```

Same output.

Comment: Tried the Element tree but still got NoneType has no attribute of sev0issue. Tried lxml way and got empty values as well.